# StoreKit In App Purchases seem to be crashing on specific iPhone models?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm trying to identify a problem that seems to be happening on iPhone 6's but not iPhone 7's. Whenever one of my iPhone 6 users taps on the button to load my in app purchase data and display the actual in app purchase, it crashes for them. This doesn't seem to be the problem for people running iPhone 7s. I can't tell if the problem is per device model or something else

I have a function called `constructPurchasePanel()` which brings up a panel displaying my in app purchases. The title of my in app purchases is grabbed from an array of products I have stored in my Menu Scene (which is a singleton)

`constructPurchasePanel()` code

```
nameLabel.text = SceneCoordinator.shared.menuScene?.products[2].localizedTitle
nameLabel2.text = SceneCoordinator.shared.menuScene?.products[1].localizedTitle
nameLabel3.text = SceneCoordinator.shared.menuScene?.products[0].localizedTitle
```

MenuScene products array initialization

```
var products = [SKProduct]() 

MyProducts.store.requestProducts{success, products in
    if success {
       self.products = products!
    }
}
```

requestProducts() function, and my other IAP related functions. 99% of this is from Ray Wenderlich's tutorial:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2016 Razeware LLC
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */

import StoreKit

public typealias ProductIdentifier = String
public typealias ProductsRequestCompletionHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ products: [SKProduct]?) -> ()

open class IAPHelper : NSObject  {

    static let IAPHelperPurchaseNotification = "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"
    fileprivate let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>
    fileprivate var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set<ProductIdentifier>()
    fileprivate var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
    fileprivate var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

    public init(productIds: Set<ProductIdentifier>) {
        productIdentifiers = productIds
        for productIdentifier in productIds {
            let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
            if purchased {
                purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
                print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
            } else {
                print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
            }
        }
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }

}

// MARK: - StoreKit API

extension IAPHelper {

    public func requestProducts(completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
        productsRequest?.cancel()
        productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        productsRequest!.delegate = self
        productsRequest!.start()
    }

    public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
        print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }

    public func isProductPurchased(_ productIdentifier: ProductIdentifier) -> Bool {
        return purchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
    }

    public class func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
        return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
    }

    public func restorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
}

// MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate

extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        let products = response.products
        print("Loaded list of products...")
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
        clearRequestAndHandler()

        for p in products {
            print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
        }
    }

    public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to load list of products.")
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
        clearRequestAndHandler()
    }

    private func clearRequestAndHandler() {
        productsRequest = nil
        productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
    }
}

// MARK: - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased:
                complete(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .failed:
                fail(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .restored:
                restore(transaction: transaction)
                break
            case .deferred:
                break
            case .purchasing:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    private func applyEffect(productIdentifier: String) {
        switch(productIdentifier) {
        case StackyChefProducts.smallCoinPackage:
            SKTAudio.sharedInstance.playSoundEffect("Content/purchase.wav")

            Chef.sharedInstance.money += 30000
            SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene?.updateBalance()
            for item in SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene!.endlessItems { item.updateUI() }
            for item in SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene!.upgradeItems { item.updateUI() }
        case StackyChefProducts.mediumCoinPackage:
            SKTAudio.sharedInstance.playSoundEffect("Content/purchase.wav")

            Chef.sharedInstance.money += 90000
            SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene?.updateBalance()
            for item in SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene!.endlessItems { item.updateUI() }
            for item in SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene!.upgradeItems { item.updateUI() }
        case StackyChefProducts.largeCoinPackage:
            SKTAudio.sharedInstance.playSoundEffect("Content/purchase.wav")

            Chef.sharedInstance.money += 150000
            SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene?.updateBalance()
            for item in SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene!.endlessItems { item.updateUI() }
            for item in SceneCoordinator.shared.shopScene!.upgradeItems { item.updateUI() }
        case StackyChefProducts.removeAdsProduct:
            if GameData.sharedInstance.adsOn {
                SKTAudio.sharedInstance.playSoundEffect("Content/purchase.wav")

                GameData.sharedInstance.adsOn = false
                MenuScene.removeAds.removeFromParent()
                MenuScene.bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        case StackyChefProducts.couponProduct:
            SKTAudio.sharedInstance.playSoundEffect("Content/purchase.wav")

            GameData.sharedInstance.coupons += 1
            SceneCoordinator.shared.grabBagScene?.updateCouponButton()
            SceneCoordinator.shared.grabBagScene?.updateIAPButtons()
        case StackyChefProducts.couponsProduct:
            SKTAudio.sharedInstance.playSoundEffect("Content/purchase.wav")

            GameData.sharedInstance.coupons += 3
            SceneCoordinator.shared.grabBagScene?.updateCouponButton()
            SceneCoordinator.shared.grabBagScene?.updateIAPButtons()
        default:
            print("applyEffect() shouldn't reach this")
        }
    }

    private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("complete...")
        deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

        applyEffect(productIdentifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    }

    private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

        print("restore... \(productIdentifier)")
        deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)

        applyEffect(productIdentifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
    }

    private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("fail...")
        if let transactionError = transaction.error as NSError? {
            if transactionError.code != SKErrorCode.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
                print("Transaction Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }

        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
        guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

        purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this? What I think is happening is that `constructPurchasePanel()` gets called, and products array is empty, therefore causing the crash when I try to grab a title from one of the products. This mean something must be going wrong in `requestProducts()` I believe.

I know the products exist because this code works fine for me and others running iPhone 7s, and I can purchase an IAP with no trouble

[image]

EDIT:

After talking to some more users it doesn't seem like this is necessarily a device specific thing, so I'm not sure how it's crashing for some but working for others.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this crash on my own device, but I do think I have a crash report of it in the Organizer. Do you know how I can get a stack trace from there? I see it crashes on `constructPurchasePanel()` but how do I get a full stack trace for you?

Comment: I don't seem to have any information besides that it crashed on `constructPurchasePanel()`, the function call before that is `touchesEnded()`, and before that is `main`

Comment: You can export or screenshot the stack trace from organizer?

Comment: @StevenOjo Thanks for sticking with me, I added what information they gave me in the organizer

Answer (score 1):

The app crash because `products` not complete load at the time you call `constructPurchasePanel()`

You need load products before you use it:
`SceneCoordinator.shared.menuScene?.products[2].localizedTitle`

Like suggest from Ray Wenderlich's tutorial, make sure you `requestProducts()` function before, best solution is use in viewDidAppear method.

Comment: I load my products with `requestProducts()` before I call `constructPurchasePanel()`. `requestProducts()` gets called in my MenuScene which is the first Scene when the player opens the game

Comment: But you need check `requestProducts()` finish load before use.
In my case, i use `if products.count > 0` before call `menuScene?.products[2]`

Comment: Why would it be the case that the products wouldn't load? Just curious

Comment: I think to load  `products` need time to request and receive response from StoreKit

Comment: Is there a reason it would still not be loaded after a couple of minutes though?